# UITableView won't uncheck the first selected row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView where the user should be able to select (check) multiple rows.

I have an NSMutableArray in my controller to hold the selected items, and in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I check whether the item is in that array and return the cell in a checked/unchecked state accordingly.

Here's the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = kContactCellReuseIdentifier;
    static NSString *searchIdentifier = kContactSearchCellReuseIdentifier;

    POContactCell *cell;

    // Configure the cell...
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell = (POContactCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.contact = self.contacts[indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"Returned cell with name %@", cell.contact.name);
    } else {
        cell = (POContactCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:searchIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.contact = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
    }

    if ([self.selectedContacts containsObject:cell.contact])
    {
        NSLog(@"was checked");
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    POContactCell* tappedCell = (POContactCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"Selected contact %@", tappedCell.contact.name);
    if ([self.selectedContacts containsObject:tappedCell.contact]) {
        // cell is already selected, so deselect it
        NSLog(@"It's already selected, so deselect it");
        [self.selectedContacts removeObject:tappedCell.contact];
        tappedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"It's not already selected, so select it");
        [self.selectedContacts addObject:tappedCell.contact];
        tappedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:NO];
}
```

This code works... except for the first selection. The first cell that the user taps will get checked and will never get unchecked. I see from the log statements that all the cells are going through the exact same process and it's correctly recognizing the selection state of the first tapped row too, even though the accessory view doesn't reflect it.

After the first selection, all the other rows work perfectly.

Any debugging ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting `self.contacts[indexPath.row]` (or `self.searchResults[indexPath.row]`, as appropriate) in your array of selected items, and checking whether or not those objects exist or not in the array when the user taps a cell. You are almost doing that, it would appear, by setting `cell.contact` to the object from your data source and checking for `cell.contact` in your array. But I'd try putting the object directly into your array, e.g.

```
id contact = self.contacts[indexPath.row];
if ([self.selectedContacs containsObject:contact])
    ...
```

and stop checking if `cell.contact` is in the array to determine "selected-ness".

In a `UITableView` there is a small set of actual `UITableViewCell` objects in memory, and they get re-used. The root of your problem could very well be this, because you are checking to see if `cell.contact` is in your set of selected items; when a cell is reused, unless you wrote your own `prepareForReuse`, the previous value of your custom attributes may not (likely will not) be cleared.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I just tried working only with the self.contacts array. Still have the same issue.

Comment: Did you change the code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to pull out a contact from the appropriate array (self.contacts or self.searchResults) and then check to see if that object is in your array of selected items?

Comment: Yep, so now `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` has `self.contacts[indexPath.row]` for checking containment or adding/removing stuff. But still the same result.

Comment: It might be worth adding an `isSelected` BOOL attribute to your objects, which would eliminate the need to track them in a separate array and you could dump that array entirely. What do you think about that idea?

Comment: I can try it but I don't think that's it. I see from the my log statements that the selection is happening correctly. But the first checkmark is never disappearing, even though if I tap on that first row twice, it won't be in the selection array anymore.

Comment: I was only suggesting eliminating potential problem sources. Simple is always better, but I hear you. Verify that the table you think you are working with is the one you are working with, i.e. main table vs search results table. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you do make that check, which affects where you look for items, but in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you do not. It seems unlikely perhaps that that could be causing your issue, but at this point you need to verify everything even if you think "I know that code is Ok." :-)

Comment: I did try it, but it didn't fix it. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I get the cell by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and passing in the tableView. But the interesting thing I just tried is that once the view loaded, I went right into search. In there, I don't have that issue, so I'm gonna dig around a bit more to see if that clue leads somewhere.

Comment: Well, I just found if I replace the `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:NO];` line with `[tableView reloadData]`, it solves my problem. But I could potentially have a large number of cells and don't want to do that.

Comment: Ah! Right. I've run into this myself. From what I have read elsewhere you should wrap that call to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` between calls to `beginUpdate` and `endUpdates`. Give that a try.

Comment: Nope, no luck with any of that. It's pretty clear to me that my logic makes sense. It's something in reloading a single row that causes weird behaviour. It's really baffling because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets triggered and returns a cell with the correct accessory type. Only the first one never gets updated in the view.